# jQuery: Reverse inserted date in input

Tags: date, input, format, reverse, mask

I'm using a jQuery plugin called [masked input](http://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/) for inserting date in wanted format. The problem is, when someone wants to insert a date which is in format of `dd.mm.yyyy` and I want the input as `yyyy-mm-dd`, sort of reverse.

Example, if you want to insert "17.06.2013", you got in input 2013-06-17. Now, the slash part is solved, but right order can be fixed with reversing of numbers or something else?

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/ubMMb/

HTML:

```
<input id="date" tabindex="1" type="text">
```

Script:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#date").mask("9999-99-99");
});
```

How can it be solved? Is there some simple solution or I must look for something more serious?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```js
jQuery(function($){
   $("#date").mask("9999-99-99", {completed:function(){
       var date = this.val();
       var matches = date.match(/(.*)\-(.*)\-(.*)/);
       var date_format = matches[3] + "." + matches[2] + "." + matches[1];

       console.log(date_format);
   } });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I tested that in the jsfiddle provided.